# I want to increment a number and insert $i values from a csv array #confused

Tags: html, css, bash

i made this #Swatch(https://codepen.io/ricoThaka/pen/YzMVdXj?editors=1100 <~)  i want to expand it to a flexible layout that can contain unlimited colors for the swatch

```
`
    .swatch div:nth-child(1) { background: DeepPink;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(2) { background: cyan;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(3) { background: GreenYellow;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(4) { background: CornflowerBlue;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(5) { background: Coral;}
`
```

Thats the values that i want to exponentially increment and manipulate  in a nice #CSSGRid that kinda spider webs to my wife phone screen, thats how we talk @normani

```
`    i=1
    until [ $i -gt 8 ];
    do
     echo ".swatch div:nth-child($i){ background: ;}"
      ((i=i+1))
    done 

    .swatch div:nth-child(1){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(2){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(3){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(4){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(5){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(6){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(7){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(8){ background: ;}
`
```

how do i get the background hex values loaded? im storing them in a file ~>

````
`    ``` for i in `cat colorvalues.csv`; do echo "$i"; done ``` 
#9acd32
#efcc00
#ffd300
#ffae42
#ffef00
#fefe33
#0014a8
#2c1608... like i want to feed that list like this 
    .swatch div:nth-child(1){ background: #xxxxxx ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(2){ background: #xxxxxx ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(3){ background: #xxxxxx ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(4){ background: #xxxxxx ;}
`
````

#BASH_iNTERPETER = https://www.onlinegdb.com/edit/0LXwgPkFV

its supposed to create a bunch of divs i just paste into my css file the divs in the html r empty [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOMak.png)
`

```
  i=1
    until [ $i -gt 8 ];
    do
      echo ".swatch div:nth-child($i){ background: ;}"
      ((i=i+1))
    done 

    .swatch div:nth-child(1){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(2){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(3){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(4){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(5){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(6){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(7){ background: ;}
    .swatch div:nth-child(8){ background: ;}


    ...Program finished with exit code 0
    Press ENTER to exit console.`
```

Comment: Your link to onlinegdb results in "Not Found".

Comment: You're using the wrong tool. Using a Bash script to parse and modify HTML is guaranteed to produce incorrect results other than for trivial cases. Beyond that observation, your question is incoherent -- even allowing for the fact that English is obviously not your native language.

Comment: you've provided a sample set of 8 lines from `colorvalues.csv`; please update the question to show the expected output for those same 8 lines

Answer (score 3):

If the main requirement is to take lines from `colorvalue.csv` and generate a series of `.swatch div:...` lines:

```
cnt=0                     # initialize counter

while read -r line
do
    printf ".swatch div:nth-child(%s){ background: %s ;}\n" $((++cnt)) "${line}"
done < colorvalues.csv
```

This generates:

```
.swatch div:nth-child(1){ background: #9acd32 ;}
.swatch div:nth-child(2){ background: #efcc00 ;}
.swatch div:nth-child(3){ background: #ffd300 ;}
.swatch div:nth-child(4){ background: #ffae42 ;}
.swatch div:nth-child(5){ background: #ffef00 ;}
.swatch div:nth-child(6){ background: #fefe33 ;}
.swatch div:nth-child(7){ background: #0014a8 ;}
.swatch div:nth-child(8){ background: #2c1608 ;}
```

**NOTE:** I'm guessing this is the desired output since OP hasn't (yet) provided the expected output

Comment: https://codepen.io/ricoThaka/pen/yLrXYry it really works out `cnt=0 ` #humor

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Maybe something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
make_swatches() {
    counter=1
    swatches=''
    input_file=$1
    limit=$2
    template=".swatch div:nth-child(%d){ background: %s; }"
    while read swatch; do
        swatches+="$(printf "$template\n" "$counter" "$swatch")"$'\n'
        ((counter++))
        [[ "$counter" -gt "$limit" ]] && break
    done < "$input_file"
    echo "$swatches"
}

make_swatches colorvalues.csv 8
```